# How can I get the ratio of a certain column based on other column with different values in SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery

In this case, I am trying to get the ratio of warehouses in [KY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kentucky) and warehouses in [TN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennessee).

```
| warehouse_id | state |
|     1        | KY    |
|     2        | KY    |
|     3        | TN    |
|     4        | TN    |
|     5        | TN    |
|     6        | FL    |
```

for example.

I tried the WHERE clause, but it limited myself to only one state.

I tried a subquery too:

```
SELECT
   (
     SELECT
       COUNT(DISTINCT warehouse_id)
     FROM table
     WHERE
       state = 'KY'
   ) AS one,

   (
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT warehouse_id)
     FROM table
     WHERE
       state = 'TN'
   ) AS two,

   one/two as ratio

FROM table
```

Comment: What desired result according provided data? Also mark used DBMS version

Comment: it would be a column named 'ratio' with one value of 0.666667. I will, I am still getting used to the features.

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/69081e56fda9d82a65a28ad5264dcb24/

Comment: Yes. But imagine now we have 3 columns "seller_id", "product_id", and  "product_category". The "seller_id" column is the primary key. "product_id" is able to have duplicates. "product_category" column has 4 different values (room, kitchen, garden, and bath). How could we calculate the ratio of products in room vs garden?

Comment: Dear @Lucas, how your comment related to data provided in your question? Your question is about 2 columns table

Comment: Ratios (division), integers, and SQL. How is this not a duplicate? We are at [663,526 SQL questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql).

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `COUNT` with a `CASE` statement in the same query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN state = 'KY' THEN warehouse_id END) /
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN state = 'TN' THEN warehouse_id END) AS ratio
FROM w;
```

Test it here: https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/240255e9751046d9d1306320befddd09/

In PostgreSQL, you can use `FILTER` like:

```
SELECT
    (COUNT(DISTINCT warehouse_id) FILTER ( WHERE state = 'KY' ))::NUMERIC /
    (COUNT(DISTINCT warehouse_id) FILTER ( WHERE state = 'TN' ))::NUMERIC
    AS ratio
FROM w;
```

with the same result.

https://sqlize.online/sql/psql15/66b76627b81c2902ec1ed30b3f785d2d/

Comment: `case` _expression_. Still upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

In [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), you need to cast your denominator as float.

```
SELECT 2 / CAST( 3 AS FLOAT);
```